# Correct "cannot open shared object file" error, but incorrect file reported in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, shared-libraries

In Cygwin, I have an executable linked to shared libraries, for the sake of the question `cygA.dll` and `cygB.dll` (and more, but not relevant here). To my knowledge one should use `PATH` for shared library paths in Cygwin, which is where I had `cygA.dll` on already. I then tried to run the executable, expecting an error that `cygB.dll` could not be found. To my surprise, I got `error while loading shared libraries: cygA.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Inspecting with `ldd` showed no entry of either .dll, but `cygcheck` correctly reported `cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygB.dll`

I also have a different executable with the same shared link to `cygA.dll`, which ran without issue.
Upon putting the path to `cygA.dll` on the `PATH`, my new executable also runs without issue. So Cygwin could not find `cygB.dll` but incorrectly reported `cygA.dll` as the missing one. This could be painful for a large project ... ***is this expected behavior, or a bug***? In the latter case, a bug of what? Should I report it to Cygwin itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a secondary level DLL is missing cygwin see only the failure of loading the first level DLL. Windows does not pass the info

you can have the corrent info using strace
EG:

```
$ cygcheck gm.exe
Found: D:\cygwin64\bin\gm.exe
D:\cygwin64\bin\gm.exe
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygGraphicsMagick-3.dll
    D:\cygwin64\bin\cygbz2-1.dll
...

$ mv cygbz2-1.dll cygbz2-1.dll-bk

 $ strace -o /tmp/gm.strace /usr/bin/gm.exe --help
D:/cygwin64/bin/strace.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open
 shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But windows correctly provides a popup info:

[image]